# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'co_code'

Tags: python

```
from dis import disassemble


def main1():
    a=12
    print(a)


disassemble(main1)
```

The code above gives the error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'co_code'`, can anyone help?

Comment: Use `dis.dis`, not `dis.disassemble`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.disassemble

you need write expression correct

```
disassemble(main1.__code__)
```

or

```
from dis import dis

def main1():
    a=12
    print(a)

dis(main1)
```